# CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION equivalent for socket adapter in Zend_Http_client

Tags: sockets, configuration, adapter, zend-http-client

I would like to use the socket adapter instead of Curl for my code but however this the problem i am facing.

(case 1 :) I am querying a server for response using Zend_http_client (default socket adapter) and I am getting a 404 error,

(case 2 :) while, for the same server as above, I am getting a response back when using CURL adapter with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to boolean true. Also, if I remove this parameter (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION) from the config array , I get the same error as in the case 1.

So, setting the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION should be doing the trick (yes, there is internal redirection happening in the target server) and hence I am looking for an equivalent parameter/option for in case of Socket Adapter.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance